# TypeError: child.send is not a function

Tags: angular

I have problem when run building Angular APP

```
npm run build
```

Local all tasks run ok and project builded, but when start command on server via console (ssh) I have this error:

```
child.send({ module: forkModule })
      ^
TypeError: child.send is not a function
```

Server **unaman -a**:

```
Linux s#################.org 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 22 10:39:25 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Angular: **"@angular/core": "^7.2.1"**

node: **v11.12.0**

npm: **6.7.0**

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm/issues/72) on GitHub described a similar issue and `npm ci` ended up doing the trick for me.